# Journey Builder Error - Binding Data Bound Member

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I've been receiving this gem of an error message in Journey Builder for one use case:

> Failed -
>   ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Activities.EntryModes.ContactStatusActivity.Status:
>   Error binding data bound member.

We used to see similar errors back in the day when records weren't on the All Subscribers list or the Channel Address Order wasn't set properly, but that shouldn't apply here. Background information:

- Salesforce Data Entry Event
- Data is also being synchronized from Sales Cloud
- Error contacts also exist on the All Subscribers from previous email sends
- First activity is wait period to ensure data has enough time to syncs from Sales Cloud
- Error appears to happen at decision split that references synchronized data

I have a support case active as this may be specific to this account, but thought I'd see if anybody has seen this error recently

Comment: lol @ `gem` of an error

Comment: anyone has an update on this one?...am getting this error too